# Accepting ETH as a payment on Binance Smart Chain

Tags: ethereum, binance, marketplace, nft

I have some doubts need to be cleared

I heard you can't send Bitcoin to Ethereum Wallet and the vice versa is also not valid.
What about sending BNB to Ethereum Wallet or the vice versa ?
Can we have BNB in Ethereum Wallet or ETH in Binance Wallet ?

If the answer is yes, since the are basically almost the same (ERC20 and BEP20).
Then is it possible to sell dan receive NFT from Binance Marketplace using ETH currency or using BNB in Ethereum marketplace ?

I asked this question because I want to make a marketplace based on Binance chain contract, but still able to accept ETH as the payment.

I need some clarification for this.
Thank you

Comment: "I heard you can't send Bitcoin to Ethereum Wallet and the vice versa " for professional questions it is better to cite the source of the information in the form a link, as hearing from the sources is usually untrusted or incorrect information.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we have BNB in Ethereum Wallet or ETH in Binance Wallet ?

Yes. Through [bridges](https://www.binance.org/en/bridge). It is a bridged token, a [custodian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65009246/what-does-non-custodial-mean) based solution.

> Then is it possible to sell dan receive NFT from Binance Marketplace using ETH

This is a business question to Binance Marketplace developer support, not for generic programming forum. There are no Binance business people here who can answer your question.

Comment: I guess you misunderstood my question here. As I said above. I planned to make my own marketplace, which has contract deployed on binance.  I did not mean the official binance marketplace. Either way, Thank you for your answer

Comment: No problem. In that case, the answer is yes. People just need to move their ETH from Ethereum mainnet to Binance Smart Chain first through the bridge. Then you can accept ETH like any other BEP20 token.

Comment: I see. I think I kind of understand what you mean. So, there is ETH version on Ethereum Mainnet and another version of ETH in Binance Smart Chain. 
I can accept ETH in my own custom Binance Marketplace, as long as it it ETH version of Binance Smart Chain. I hope I got this right.